# Angular - Interceptor always get null value accessing the accessToken from localStorage

Tags: angular

the jwtToken is not added to the authorization header because the interceptor tries to access it before it's set in the local storage.. hence that the setJwtToken method from the authService works well and sets the token and store it in the locals storage and I get its value wherever I try to access it in the project.. I don't know what's wrong about the interceptor. I only use one interceptor and provided it in the providers array in the app.module.

token.interceptor.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject, from, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, switchMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';
import { TokenDTO } from '../_models/tokenDTO';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router:Router) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.auth.getJwtToken()}`,
      },
    });

    return next.handle(req);
  }
  handleUnAuthorizedError(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler){
    let tokeApiModel = new TokenDTO();
    tokeApiModel.token = this.auth.getRefreshToken()!;
    tokeApiModel.refreshToken = this.auth.getRefreshToken()!;
    return this.auth.renewToken(tokeApiModel)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((data:TokenDTO)=>{
        this.auth.storeRefreshToken(data.refreshToken);
        this.auth.storeAccessToken(data.token);
        req = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {Authorization:`Bearer ${data.token}`} 
        })
        return next.handle(req);
      }),
      catchError((err)=>{
        return throwError(()=>{
          this.router.navigate(['login'])
        })
      })
    )
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { TokenDTO } from '../_models/tokenDTO';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { JwtHelperService, JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { EmployeeCodeProviderService } from './employee-code-provider.service';
import { RegisterDTO } from '../_models/registerDTO';

@Injectable({ 
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private baseUrl = 'https://localhost:7091/api/User';
  private userPayload:any;
  private accessTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<string | null> = new BehaviorSubject<string | null>(null);
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private jwtHelper:JwtHelperService, private employeeCodeProviderService:EmployeeCodeProviderService) {
    this.userPayload = this.decodeToken();
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    this.accessTokenSubject.next(accessToken);
  }

  login(credentials: any) {
    return this.http.post<TokenDTO>(`${this.baseUrl}/Login`, credentials)
  }
  
  getJwtTokenObservable(): Observable<string | null> {
    return this.accessTokenSubject.asObservable();
  }

  register(credentials:RegisterDTO):Observable<TokenDTO>{
    return this.http.post<TokenDTO>(`${this.baseUrl}/Register`, credentials);
  }

  logout(): void {
    localStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  removeTokens() {
    localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
    localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");
  }

  storeAccessToken(accessToken: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken)
  }

  getJwtToken(){
    return localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
  }
    
    

  storeRefreshToken(tokenValue: string){
    localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', tokenValue)
  }

  getRefreshToken(){
    return localStorage.getItem('refreshToken')
  }


  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
  
    if (accessToken) {
      const isTokenExpired = this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(accessToken);
  
      if (isTokenExpired) {
        this.removeTokens();
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  
    return false;
  }
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { NgToastService } from 'ng-angular-popup';
import ValidateForm from 'src/app/_helpers/validationForm';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/_services/auth.service';
import { EmployeeCodeProviderService } from 'src/app/_services/employee-code-provider.service';
import { UserStoreService } from 'src/app/_services/user-store.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public loginForm!: FormGroup;
  loginError: boolean = false;
  lockedOut: boolean = false;
  constructor(
    private fb:FormBuilder,
    private authService:AuthService,
    private jwtHelper: JwtHelperService, 
    private router: Router, 
    private toast: NgToastService, 
    private employeeCodeProviderService: EmployeeCodeProviderService, 
    private userStore:UserStoreService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      employeeCode: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    });
  }

   onSubmit() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      const credentials = {
        employeeCode: this.loginForm.value.employeeCode,
        password: this.loginForm.value.password
      };

      this.authService.login(credentials).subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          this.loginForm.reset();
          this.authService.storeAccessToken(response.token);
          this.authService.storeRefreshToken(response.refreshToken);
          this.employeeCodeProviderService.setEmployeeCode(credentials.employeeCode)
          console.log(localStorage.getItem('accessToken'))
          const tokenPayload = this.authService.decodeToken();          
          this.userStore.setFullNameForStore(tokenPayload['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier']);
          this.userStore.setRoleForStore(tokenPayload['http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role']);
          this.toast.success({detail : "SUCCESS", summary: "Login Successful!", duration:5000});
          this.router.navigate(['home']);
        },
        error : (err) => {
          this.toast.error({detail:"ERROR!", summary : "Something went wrong!", duration: 5000});
          console.log (err);
        },
      });
      
    } else {
      ValidateForm.validateAllFormFields(this.loginForm);
    }
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { CategoriesModule } from './categories/categories.module';
import { ItemsModule } from './items/items.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { MultiSelectModule } from 'primeng/multiselect';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
import { DepartmentsModule } from './departments/departments.module';
import { IngredientsModule } from './ingredients/ingredients.module';
import { EmployeesModule } from './employees/employees.module';
import { OrdersModule } from './orders/orders.module';
import { PipesModule } from './pipes/pipes.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './authentication/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './authentication/register/register.component';
import { JWT_OPTIONS, JwtHelperService, JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { AuthTokenService } from './_services/auth-token.service';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './_interceptors/token.interceptor';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, HeaderComponent, HomeComponent, LoginComponent, RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CoreModule,
    CategoriesModule,
    ItemsModule,
    DepartmentsModule,
    IngredientsModule,
    EmployeesModule,
    OrdersModule,
    MultiSelectModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    PipesModule
  ],
  exports:[],
  providers:[
{
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    JwtHelperService,{ provide: JWT_OPTIONS, useValue: JWT_OPTIONS }    
    ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

that's all. I'm stuck here for like 2 days and I don't know what's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

instead of overriding same request create new request object

```
let newRequest = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.auth.getJwtToken()}`,
      },
    });

return next.handle(newRequest);
```

Comment: same. it adds the authorization header but with null value for the JWT token.
Authorization : Bearer null
the auth.getJwtToken() is not performing properly in the interceptor, although it works anywhere in the project.

Comment: additionally, when I logout and make another login request without a refresh, I get the authorization header with the jwt token!! it's all about the first request. the interceptor tries to access the jwtToken from localStorage before it's even stored.

Comment: Oh in that can you can use addition header to avoid adding auth token in certain request

like this

in interceptor

// ignore Auth
    if (request.headers.get("ignoreAuth") === "true") {
      const patch = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.delete("ignoreAuth"),
      });
      return next.handle(patch);
    }

add "ignoreAuth": true header in request you dont want to add auth token , Simple yet effective hack